# How to skip one view from listview?

Tags: android, list, android-arrayadapter

I am using following to fill my listview and don't want to display item if I clicked on btn_Delete, I successfully removed item from hasValues but it shows me the blank item in listview,
I want to remove this blank listview item from List.

If any body knows how to do this please reply .
Thanks,

```
private class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
    {
        private List<HashMap<String, String>> myData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<HashMap<String, String>> objects)
        {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            context = getContext();
            myData = objects;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View v = convertView;
            try
            {
                if(v == null)
                {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listSomeThing, null);
                }
                if(hasValues != null && !hasValues.get(DatabaseConstant.key_STATUS).equals("D"))
                {
                    btn_Delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) 
                        {
                            // delete item from HasValues..
                        }
                }
else
{
    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}               
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Utility.saveExceptionDetails(LogsDetails.this, e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return v;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i think this is not the best solution for this purpose. just try to set your specific condition and increase your position number in getView.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove it from your Array `myData` and than call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your ListView Adapter.
Otherwise getView will be called and the List Item will be populated, if there is `hasValues` or not, Because the View will be returned. (Don't try to return null instead - it won't work).

Answer (score 0):

You can create method that will delete items from your List and then inform Adapter that data has changed.

```
btn_Delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) 
   {
   deleteItemAtId(position);
   }
};
```

and then create this method:

```
void deleteItemAtId(int id)
{
   myData.remove(id);
   // This ensure that getView is called again
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the element from the list in custom view activity and store that to some temp list and pass that temp list to your custom adapter. You cannot do anything in custom adapter.